# Take a screnshot of a Window in TCL

Tags: scripting, tcl, screenshot

I have an application written in TCL. I want to be able to run a script that captures a screenshot of a window as a PNG, BMP, etc.

I've looked at this wiki page (http://wiki.tcl.tk/9127), but I think I read that the Img package only works for tcl 8.4.

I've also tried `image create photo -format window -data %W`, but I get an error saying "image format 'window' is not supported".

Is there a solution to capture and save a TCL window for tcl8.6?

Answer (score 2):

This *ought* to be what's required to make that code work:

```
package require img::window
```

It's a sub-package of Img and should most certainly be supported on 8.6. (Mind you, you might have problems on OSX; the ActiveState build of Img on that platform appears to be broken.)

In general, if a package is supported in Tcl/Tk 8.**X** then it's supported in 8.**Y** too (were **Y** ≥ **X**). There are a few exceptions to that rule (the main ones to note are probably TclOO, [incr Tcl] and BLT, because they poke their fingers into Tcl very deeply) but they're just that: exceptions.

Comment: TclOO is built into 8.6 and [incr Tcl] 4 should ship with 8.6, so they're not problematic. It's just that the separate package version of TclOO is for 8.5 only and [incr Tcl] 3 won't work with 8.6 due to changes in internal structures. BLT… BLT is its own thing.

Comment: Afaik BLT has 2 problems: assumptions of the result type of `Tcl_New*Obj` and using `interp->result`, but I can be wrong.

Comment: BLT certainly _used_ to have deeper problems than that, like patching the implementation of hash tables…